# import google analytics report in html page

Tags: html, google-analytics, reporting

I am having a requirement of showing google analytics report in the HTML page.I mean without login into Google Analytics , I have to show the report directly into the webpage.Is it possible ,kindly let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Do some serverside scripting with your favourite programming language to draw data from the Google Analytics reporting API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/)

**Option2:**
Use Google Apps Script to pull data from you GA account. Create a graph from the data. Embed graph in Google Sites webpage. Embed Google Sites page in your site via iframe

**Option3**
Use Google Apps Script to pull data from you GA account. Create Json/XML-Feed via Apps Script. Pull Feed from Apps Script and parse it into your site via Javascript.

So it's doable (but not via Javascript alone without your visitors logging in to the GA Account in the Browser) but requires more programming than conveniently can be explained in a stackoverflow answer - maybe you could explore one of the options and then come back for specifics.

Comment: Thanx Eike , I ll check and get back to you, by the way I have come across this link:-http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/results?category=Reporting%20Tools for reporting tool, lets see this can also help

Comment: I also found this: http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/about?app_id=421002 by searching for "google analytics public widget". My issue with these type of services is that you need to trust them with login information for the GA account - usually not an option for clients sites.

Comment: I need support for both desktop & mobile app so I have to search for such an option that ll work fine on all type of devices, I ll give a try on all your 3 options.

Comment: Hey Eike, I tried using Google App Script and Google Spreadsheet,its working, can you tell me how to customize spreadsheet link into a graph or simple text box type popup in HTML page

Comment: Atlast I find out the solution , I have used Google App script and Google Spreadsheet for importing Google Analytics data, then using jquery I fetched the published spreadsheet to show Report in my application's webpage

Comment: If you don't want to deal with the API check out [embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  We support html5-based charts, tables, access to the real-time data.  White-labeling also available to integrate into content management systems (CMS).  _(disclosure - I work with the company)_